# How to implement linear flow with IO and Either functors in functional programming with javascript?

Tags: javascript, io, functional-programming, functor, either

Result: linear flow like `getFile(filename).map(parseJson).map(doOtherThings)...`

When I'm using `Either` itself everything is nice and easy

```
function doSomethingCrazyHere(){
  return "something crazy";
}

function safeUnsureFunction(){
    try{
       return Right(doSomethingCrazyHere());
    }catch(e){
       return Left(e);
    }
}
```

then I can just do the following

```
safeUnsureFunction().map((result)=>{
  // result is just result from doSomethingCrazyHere function
  // everything is linear now - I can map all along
  return result;
})
.map()
.map()
.map()
.map();
// linear flow
```

problem is when I'm using IO like:

```
function safeReadFile(){
  try{
    return Right(fs.readFileSync(someFile,'utf-8'));
  }catch(e){
    return Left(error);
  }
}

let pure=IO.from(safeReadFile).map((result)=>{
  // result is now Either
  // so when I want to be linear I must stay here
  // code from now on is not linear and I must generate here another chain

  return result.map(IdontWant).map(ToGo).map(ThisWay).map(ToTheRightSideOfTheScreen);
})
.map((result)=>{
  return result.map(This).map(Is).map(Wrong).map(Way);
})
.map(IwantToBeLienearAgain)
.map(AndDoSomeWorkHere)
.map(ButMapFromIOreturnsIOallOverAgain);

let unpure=function(){
  return pure.run();
}
```

IO is for separating pure from not so pure functions right?

So I want to separate unpure file read with also Either file error handling. Is this possible?

How to have linear flow when using Eithers inside IO monads?

Is there any pattern in functional programming for this?

`readFile(filename).map(JSON.parse).map(doSomethingElse)....`

Comment: might have a look here https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land

Answer (score 2):

Only way for this could be to add `safeRun` method to the `IO`
so at the end we will have `Either` and we will gracefully recover from error

```
class safeIO {
  // ...

  safeRun(){
    try{
      return Right(this.run());
    }catch(e){
      return Left(e);
    }
  }

  //...
}
```

Instead of `safeReadFile` that returns `Either` we must use normal `readFile`

```
function readFile(){
    return fs.readFileSync(someFile,'utf-8');
}

let pure = safeIO.from(readFile)
.map((result)=>{
  // result is now file content if there was no error at the reading stage
  // so we can map like in normal IO
  return result;
})
.map(JSON.parse)
.map(OtherLogic)
.map(InLinearFashion);

let unpure = function(){
  return pure.safeRun(); // -> Either Left or Right
}
```

or take the `try catch` logic outside an `IO` to the `unpure` function itself without modyfing any `IO`

```
let unpure = function(){
  try{
    return Right(pure.run());
  }catch(e){
    return Left(e);
  }
}
unpure(); // -> Either
```